# How to parse 4 digit years (e.g., 2021) in pandas to get year end dates (12/31/2021)? Currently the parser assigns beginning of year (1/1/2021)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime-format

I'm trying to read a CSV file to a pandas dataframe. The file has dates as 4 digit numbers (e.g., 2001, 2002). Is there a way to convert the 4 digit year to a full year-end format date (12/31/2001) via the parse_date in read_csv?

Comment: Can you provide the full code you currently use to load your data?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like that and solve like this:

I had a variable called `my_year`

```
date = ('12'+ "/" + '31'+ "/" + my_year)
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply and give either a function or a `lambda` function

#### Dummy data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([2020 for _ in range(20)], columns=["year"])
df
```

Output:

```
    year
0   2020
1   2020
2   2020
3   2020
4   2020
5   2020
6   2020
7   2020
8   2020
9   2020
10  2020
11  2020
12  2020
13  2020
14  2020
15  2020
16  2020
17  2020
18  2020
19  2020
```

### `apply`

Here we apply a string concatenation using fstring:

```
df["year"] = df["year"].apply(lambda row: f'12/31/{row}')
df
```

Output:

```
          year
0   12/31/2020
1   12/31/2020
2   12/31/2020
3   12/31/2020
4   12/31/2020
5   12/31/2020
6   12/31/2020
7   12/31/2020
8   12/31/2020
9   12/31/2020
10  12/31/2020
11  12/31/2020
12  12/31/2020
13  12/31/2020
14  12/31/2020
15  12/31/2020
16  12/31/2020
17  12/31/2020
18  12/31/2020
19  12/31/2020
```